# changing from title to title format

Tags: entries, channels, titles

We built a small conference site last year that had a Speakers channel. At the time, we used the title field to store the last name of a speaker. That was fine but for editors, where there are speakers with the same last name, it's become confusing.

So I thought we'd be able to switch to using title format of `{title}, {speakerFirstName}`

This works but involves having to resave the entries which isn't a huge deal but would be great if there was a way to update these all at once?

Comment: also, going this route makes it impossible to update the title field as the last name (not that I can see that changing) but would be good to be able to create a new field of `speakerLastName` and have that inherit `title` somehow.